# How to generate table from HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

So, I have to generate multiple tables from the HTML code. I can be generating multiple tables using pure javascript code but its too difficult to assign ids and getting its value. as I wrote javascript function **generate_table**
so I have created one sample HTML table from that HTML TAble how to generate the same Table again(multiple times). I have written too much javascript code for tables TD and TR. How to reduce that code.
**I have many tables I want to regenerate the specific table so I cant use `<table>` tag**. Any hint ? code sample ?

```js
function generate_table() {
  // get the reference for the body
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

  // creates a <table> element and a <tbody> element
  var tbl = document.createElement('table');
  var tblBody = document.createElement('tbody');

  // creating all cells
  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    var seqnumber = 1;
    var seq = +1;
    // creates a table row
    
    var row2 = document.createElement('tr');

    

    //====== table first row data =======//
    var seq = document.createElement('td');
    var seqText = document.createTextNode('Seq');
    var l = document.createElement('td');
    var seqText1 = document.createElement('input');

   

    //===== seq generator =====//
    seq.appendChild(seqText);
    row2.appendChild(seq);
    l.appendChild(seqText1);
    row2.appendChild(l);

   

    // add the row to the end of the table body
    tblBody.appendChild(row2);
  
  }

  // put the <tbody> in the <table>
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  // appends <table> into <body>
  body.appendChild(tbl);
  // sets the border attribute of tbl to 2;
  tbl.setAttribute('border', '2');
}
```

```css
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<h3> TABLE FROM JAVA SCRIPT</h3>
<input type="button" value="Generate a table." onclick="generate_table()" />

<h3> TABLE FROM HTML</h3>

<table id="table6">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Aggregator</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th> Column Name </th>
    <th> Function </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
      
<input type="button" value="Generate same table from HTML." />
```

JSfiddle Link : - >https://jsfiddle.net/shreekantbatale2/evqsuxm8/5/

Comment: There's nothing wrong with long code. Howeber, if you're willing to trade performance for code size, you should go to [Code Golf SE](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @D.Pardal thanks Sir, But I want to regenerate the same table from HTML! HTML javascript code combination is fine!

Comment: You should try it with jQuery. It's Way easier just $(`<table></table>') and append to somewhere

Comment: @Edig what if I have multiple tables and I have to regenerate only some od the table

Comment: @ShreeBatale You can create a template in a json file or something similar and load it and Just create as you need. for example $('.table).append(template.header). If you need to replicate an existing without a template. You need to detect what you want to regenerate based on some class or something you can detect

Comment: What kind of things do you want to change or vary in your the newly created tables?

Comment: @D.Pardal no! code golf is for programming challenges (=coding for fun), not production code. Did you mean [codereview.se] (but they, too, have standards)?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier there no any changes

Comment: @D.Pardal okay sir!

Comment: @Edig I'm completing new to this

Comment: This question will _not_ be accepted on Code Golf. Or even Code Review, because only functional code is allowed on Code Review.

Comment: @ShreeBatale So basically you want to copy and paste a table? Please explain a little more your goal

Comment: @Edig, not a just copy-paste I have to regenerate. does copy-paste help me to get a 
 table value( rows and column)? So I have created an HTML  table.  so I have to write Javascript code to regenerate that HTML table again!

Comment: @ShreeBatale check my answer, it's that what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Edig please read my comment!

Comment: @MisterJojo Yes

Comment: @MisterJojo do you have any other solution other than the below answers?

Comment: @MisterJojo Sure! but the table must be regenerated. because after regenerating I will put values in the input box to export in JSON

Comment: @Mister Jojo delete why? It was right!

Comment: Ok, I have made some changes for  adding duplicate new rows ( 5 ), did you validate my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand is that you want to add a template table. Here is a simple way to do it with jQuery

```js
var id = 0;

function generate_table() {
  var table = `<table id='table${id}'>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Aggregator</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th> Column Name </th>
      <th> Function </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <input> </td>
      <td> <input> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>`
  $('#table-template').append(table)
  id++
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3> TABLE FROM JAVA SCRIPT</h3>
<input type="button" value="Generate a table." onclick="generate_table()" />

<h3> TABLE FROM HTML</h3>

<div id='table-template'></div>

      
<input type="button" value="Generate same table from HTML." />
```

I think this is what you are lookign for.

```js
function generate_table() {
  var table = $('#table6').clone()
  table.find('input').val('')
  $('#table-template').append(table)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3> TABLE FROM JAVA SCRIPT</h3>
<input type="button" value="Generate a table." onclick="generate_table()" />

<h3> TABLE FROM HTML</h3>

<table id='table6'>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Aggregator</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th> Column Name </th>
      <th> Function </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <input> </td>
      <td> <input> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
      
<input type="button" value="Generate same table from HTML." />


<div id='table-template'></div>
```

Comment: Hey I want to regenerate table from my HTML table, not that seq one's table, is it possible to regenerate table from the table id that I have assigned '<id=table6>'

Comment: Oh ok. I got it. Just need to change the var table with the code. I'll edit it

Comment: @ShreeBatale you can edit the template code, with any you want. But If you want to grab that from the html you have. that would be copy/paste with the values. Its better when the page load, add 1 table automatically

Comment: so if I click on generate table each table will get its id like 1 2 3 4... right?

Comment: @ShreeBatale. Yes, I add another snippet that will literally clone and clean all input from your real HTML table. But remember to change the id when you clone. with `attr("id","newId");`

Comment: I don't want to display that HTML table when I open the page. the table must be displayed when I click on the generate button possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `<template>` element to generate new HTML each time you want a new `<table>`

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.js-create-table');
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Aggregator</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th> Column Name </th>
      <th> Function </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <input> </td>
      <td> <input> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
`;

function generateTable() {
  const table = template.content.cloneNode(true);
  document.body.append(table);
}

button.addEventListener('click', generateTable);
```

```html
<button class="js-create-table">Create table</button>
```

And if you just want to *clone* the original table and create a duplicate from it one.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.js-clone-table');
const table = document.querySelector('.js-table');

function cloneTable() {
  const clone = table.cloneNode(true);
  document.body.append(clone);
}

button.addEventListener('click', cloneTable);
```

```html
<button class="js-clone-table">Clone table</button>

<table class="js-table">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Aggregator</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th> Column Name </th>
    <th> Function </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what if I want to generate the table from its table id? e.g. <table id="table6">

Comment: I've added an example in which you *clone* the table from the HTML and paste it in the document. But be sure to remove any `id` attributes as they will also be cloned. Use `class` attributes instead.

Answer (score 1):

to duplicater a table with everyting inside (or any html element)

```js
const btTableCopy = document.getElementById('bt-table-copy')
  ,   originTable = document.getElementById('table6')
  ,   baseRowTbl  = originTable.querySelector('tbody tr')
  ;
var tableNum = 0
  ;
btTableCopy.onclick=()=>
  {
  let newTable = originTable.cloneNode(true)
    , newTbody = newTable.querySelector('tbody')
    ;
  newTable.id = `table-copy-${++tableNum}`  // there cannot be two identical id values on an HTML page

  for(let i=0;i<5;i++) // add 5 new rows
    {
    newTbody.appendChild(baseRowTbl.cloneNode(true))
    }
  newTable.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(inp=>inp.value='') // clear all table inputs
  document.body.appendChild(newTable)
  }
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 1em;
  }
thead {
  background-color: lightblue;
  }
td, th {
  border: solid grey 1px;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align : center;
  }
```

```html
<table id="table6">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Aggregator</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th> Column Name </th>
      <th> Function </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> <input> </td>
      <td> <input> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="bt-table-copy">copy table with 5 new rows</button>
```

Comment: what if I add some rows in the table but I want only 1st (First) row to be generated with the new table?